# Can someone explain to me why this inheiritance in javascript doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function SuperClass()
{
    var self = this;
    self.someVariable = true;
}
function SubClass()
{
    var self = this;
    self.name = "Sub";
}
SubClass.prototype = SuperClass;

var sub = new SubClass();

alert("This is a sub class with name " + sub.name + " and variable " + sub.someVariable);

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

output:

```
This is a sub class with name Sub and variable undefined
```

So how come sub class doesnt have someVariable? I thought thats the whole point of prototyping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply assigning a reference to the `SuperClass` constructor to the `SubClass.prototype`, you need to use the `new` operator to make this `SubClass.prototype` object an instance of `SuperClass`:

```
//...
SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();
//..
```

You may want to restore the `constructor` property of the `SubClass.prototype` object after the above line, because if you don't do it, the instances created with `SubClass` (like `sub` in your example) will have an inherited `constructor` property wrongly pointing to `SuperClass`:

```
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/okebi3/edit).

Recommended articles:

- [Constructors considered mildly confusing](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html)
- [Object Oriented Programming in JavaScript](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm)